# Backbone memory leak or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, memory-leaks

See my simple code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Liber/QMLEh/1/) .

Is there any memory leaks here in my code ?

Before I click the `close` button, I took Snapshot 1, after I click it, I took Snapshot 2.

So, what does it means in the picture below ?
Means there are still any reference to my `view` that's case the memory leaks ? But why ?

[image]

I'm using Backbone 1.1.2 and jQuery 1.9.1.

I've learnt something from [How To: Detect Backbone Memory Leaks](http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/how-to-detect-backbone-memory-leaks/), but still confused.

Addition: See I pointed out in the picture, here it's Red, but sometimes it's Yellow, What's the meaning of those ?

Addition:

I find some solutions here: [Backbone.js in Practice: Part I – Preventing Memory Leaks](https://paydirtapp.com/blog/backbone-in-practice-memory-management-and-event-bindings/)

But It might not the most elegance way. How @Jeremy Ashkenas think about this ? Patch something like the article mentioned `Paydirt` in to the Backbone lib ? Or add a `destruction` function to view ?

Solution:
[Zombies! RUN! (Managing Page Transitions In Backbone Apps)](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/)

Comment: I'm late on this one but seems you have already found the right link ;)

Comment: Next time try to post the solution as an answer in order for other users to see that this question has an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

[Zombies! RUN! (Managing Page Transitions In Backbone Apps)](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/)